# Swift 4 почему не срабатывает guard

Tags: swift4

Есть такой код. И в нем почему-то не срабатывает инструкция guard.

```
struct User {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var age: String
}

let firstNameTextField = UITextField()
let lastNameTextField = UITextField()
let ageTextField = UITextField()

firstNameTextField.text = "Александр"
lastNameTextField.text = "Иванов"
ageTextField.text = nil


func createUser() -> User? {

    guard let firstNameUnwrap = firstNameTextField.text else { return nil }

    guard let lastNameUnwrap = lastNameTextField.text else { return nil }

    guard let ageUnwrap = ageTextField.text else { return nil }


    return User(firstName: firstNameUnwrap, lastName: lastNameUnwrap, age: ageUnwrap)
}


if let userNew = createUser() {
    print(userNew.firstName, userNew.lastName, userNew.age)
}
```

Печатает - "Александр Иванов"

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не срабатывает guard? Ведь он должен прервать выполнение кода, поскольку ageTextField.text = nil. Т.е. на печать не должно ничего выводиться.

Answer (score 1):

Для `UITextField`  нет никакой разницы между `nil` и пустой строкой.
Отсюда 
`ageTextField.text = nil`**=**`ageTextField.text = ""`

Следовательно имеем:

```
firstNameTextField.text = "Александр"
lastNameTextField.text =  "Иванов"
ageTextField.text = ""
```

Больше информации про обработку пустых строк можно найти [здесь](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/handling-empty-optional-strings-in-swift-ba77ef627d74) .

Comment: Спасибо! И за подсказку, и за статью.

Корректно ли тогда будет сказать, что составители задачи неправильно ее составили, поскольку не учли данное обстоятельство. Или я ее неправильно решил?

Comment: Извините , а какая основная цель ?
Если написать guard, который бы прерывал код - то нет.  ( +не вижу смысла ; не хотел бы крашить мое приложение на каждой пустой строке)
Если написать код , который отработает даже для пустого вызова но вернет пустую строку - да .
Можно добавить доп. проверку для полностью пустого юзера или допилить обработчик и возвращать что-то в стиле * возраст не указан* , но это по моему скромному мнению.

Comment: Цель - решение задачи, она чисто учебная, есть тема guard, надо его реализовать в конкретном контексте. И тут вот оказывается такая засада.

Comment: и кстати, если Для UITextField нет никакой разницы между nil и пустой строкой, то как тогда быть с guard ? Ведь получается, что в данном примере он не реагирует ни на nil, ни на пустую строку.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вы можете сделать тест:

```
textField.text = nil
print("textField.text: \(textField.text)")
```

После запуска получите:

```
textField.text: Optional("")
```

Т.е. TextField всегда возвращает Optional("") вместо nil.